# Find and assign content to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need is to find an element which have *class="selected"* and than assign content of that element to a variable.

```
<a href="#">This is the content</a>
<a href="#" class="selected">This is the content</a>
<a href="#">This is the content</a>
```

Any help? Thank you

Comment: You should read a tutorial about jQuery, to learn the basics: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery The documentation is also very good: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [class operator](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

`var elementContents = $('.selected').html(); //assuming there is only one element found with the class selected`

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

var someContent =  $('[.selected](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)').[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/);

Answer (score 0):

```
var variable=$(".selected").text();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KVv3S/)

Answer (score 0):

Give it an Id, then use:

```
var content = document.getElementById("yourIdHere").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

to ensure you only get the first occurance, don't forget to instruct jQuery to only get the first, and to ensure it's readable i'd use the .text() not the .html() selector as it will strip any HTML away if there is any

```
<a href="#">This is the content</a>
<a href="#" class="selected">This is the content</a>
<a href="#">This is the content</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myVariable = $(".selected").first().text();
});
</script>
```